Local Group Policy firewall rules not listed in GPO firewall
I have 100+ rules defined as per LGP. I can see all these rules both in Local Windows Firewall in RO mode as well as in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\FirewallRules. I also can see them via ps applet:
Get-NetFirewallRule -Direction Outbound -Enabled True -Action Allow -PolicyStore ActiveStore | Select DisplayName
However, they are not displayed in LGPO MMC Firewall applet. As of today, for unknown reasons, they are not present. I have permissions to the aforementioned keys in the registry so it is not R/W issue, I can add new entries and they are added to registry and are displayed in the applet but old ones still invisible (though they ARE applied).
Exporting policy exports empty rule list. I can export a plain text list (using user-side Windows Firewall applet, which shows all rules cascading down) but it is not-reimportable.
Any idea how can I fix the rules storage without manual work? There is a LOT of rules.
